# Как правильно написать Exception чтобы программа не вылетала

Tags: java, mysql, исключения

Привет, пишу приложение которое получает данные с ПЛК Siemens и пишет их в базу.
не могу сообразить как правильно написать отловить Exception's чтобы программа не вылетала в случае отсутствия связи с ПЛК и корректно работала при появлении связи с ним.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sourceforge.snap7.moka7.S7Client.SendPacket(S7Client.java:417)
at com.sourceforge.snap7.moka7.S7Client.SendPacket(S7Client.java:425)
at com.sourceforge.snap7.moka7.S7Client.GetAgBlockInfo(S7Client.java:816)
at com.sourceforge.snap7.moka7.S7Client.DBGet(S7Client.java:846)
at app.DispatcherPLC.getDB(DispatcherPLC.java:31)
at app.DispatcherPLC.resultConnection(DispatcherPLC.java:62)
at app.DispatcherPLC.getIntData(DispatcherPLC.java:45)
at app.Main.dispatcherPLC(Main.java:52)
at app.Main.startApp(Main.java:36)
at app.Main.main(Main.java:27)
```

ссылка на гитхаб: https://github.com/nOy39/S7DataToMySQL

Приложение будет работать круглосуточно на ПК который соединен по TCP/IP с промышленным контроллером Siemens S7-314, и получать определенные данные с ПЛК, оборудование на ночь выключается и включается в 8 утра, соответсвенно при выключении оборудования приложение вылетает по NullPointerException и при запуске если оборудование еще не запущенно, хотелось бы чтобы приложение висело в режиме ожидания включения ПЛК, работало в штатном режиме при включенном ПЛК, и уходило в режим ожидания.

Comment: Объясните что за Exception вылетает и постройте воспроизводимый пример. Универсальных советов нет.

Comment: при отсутствии связи с плк вылетает NullPointerException...

Comment: Укажите все нужные сведения прямо в вопросе. Изменить текст вопроса можно с помощью кнопки «править» под ним.

Comment: Почитайте как создать [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `if(соединение == null) {ожидать соединения}`

Answer (score 0):

Может скажу не очень верно, но можешь попробовать классический

```
try{} catch(Throwable e){}
```

Comment: Брррррррр... Да ещё и `Throwable`...

Comment: @Сергей, в проекте уже отлавливается NPE.  проблема не в том, как поймать. а в том, как инициализировать обхекты, чтобы не поймать NPE